# Getting crash, when I'm trying to create GAITracker outside a .framework

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics

I have a project where we created a .framework library, which contains Google Analytics tracking. Events, logging etc. I have a specific tracker there with it's own ID.

Now I integrated this framework to my project and I would like to use Google analytics here also. The problem is, that I can't, because whenever I try to create a GAITracker, I get a BAD_ACCESS crash and the worst part: no exception in the console (see attached image).

I just use the simple GAITracker declaration:

```
 id<GAITracker> trackera = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:GoogleAnalyticsTrackingID];
```

I have run out of ideas.

[image]

Comment: What is the exact exception thrown? How do you expect people to help when you don't provide the minimal necessary information required?

Comment: No Exception thrown, that is the problem.

Comment: Enable zombie objects and see if you see something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: You can't call the [GAI sharedInstance] from a static library and a project when running the two together. 
My solution was to create a global variable inside the static library, which holds the second tracker and whenever I need to track something inside my app I'll use that public variable in the static library instead of using [GAI sharedInstance]. I'm setting up this tracker right after launch, calling the static librarys public method (setUpTrackerWithID:@"ID"). This created a [GAI sharedInstance] with the ID and stores that inside a public variable. The class inside that manages this is a singleton class of course.